# How can I pass php variables to another page without redirecting it to that page?

Tags: php, html

As a part of my college project, I'm building a web-site related to vehicle renting. Now when I click on "rent" button, I want the vehicle_id and user_id to be passed to the "notification" page of the particular user who listed the vehicle for rent on the web-site WITHOUT redirecting it to the notification page.

```
 <a href = "Waiting.php?vid=<?php echo $vid;?>&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>" ><input type="button" value="Confirm to rent" name="confirm" ></a>
```

At "Waiting.php" there is this simple message "Please wait until the owner reponds".
I haven't created the notification page yet, but I want to make sure if I can pass the the $vid and $uid (values of php variables) to the notification page, without actually redirecting to it.

Comment: Can't you use AJAX request?

Comment: Please add your code to your question so that others can see what you've attempted. Read here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am sorry for that sir. I hope it is at-least clarified that it was before.

Comment: I don't know much about AJAX. So I was just trying to stick with php. If it is possible  to do so with AJAX, kindly let me know more about it!

Answer (score -1):

you change based your requirement

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnedit btn btn-default" data-vid="<?php echo $res['sid'];  ?>" data-uid="<?php echo $res['sid'];  ?>" data-toggle="modal" title="View" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"> <i class="ti-eye"></i></a>
    <script>
                            $(document).on('click', '.btnedit', function(e) {
                              var vid= $(this).data('vid');
                               var uid = $(this).data('uid');
                                $.ajax({
                                    type : 'POST',
                                    url : base_url + 'Waiting.php',
                                    data : { 'vid' : vid,'uid ' : uid },
                                       success: function(data){
                                       $("#location").html(data.loc);

                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```